# Signal R - OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception) Function is Not working

Tags: asp.net, signalr, blazor, blazor-webassembly, signalr-hub

**I'm working on a chat application on the web using blazor web assemblly**

I'm tring to push the states(Online / Offline) of users to each others.

[image]

here is the signalRHub

[image]

On connected is working fine.

> public override Task OnConnectedAsync()

**My problem is that OnDisconnectedAsync() not getting hitted by the debuger at all**

Even after I close the client(browser) that the server is connected with.

```
    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(Context.User);


        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the client code for disconnecting, please?

Comment: @Grizzlly There is no client code when disconnecting because the user might just close the browser. I would not know if he did this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the middleware for the token on the server for signalr.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();

services.TryAddEnumerable(
    ServiceDescriptor.Singleton
        <IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>,ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>());
```

```
public class ConfigureJwtBearerOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
{
    public void PostConfigure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        var originalOnMessageReceived = options.Events.OnMessageReceived;
        options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async context =>
        {
            await originalOnMessageReceived(context);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Token))
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                    path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs"))
                {
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: This assumes your hub endpoint(s) start with "/hubs"

Comment: Thanks for the help, But Still not working :(

Comment: OnDisconnectedAsync Works only with     [AllowAnonymous]  ,
OnConnectedAsync Works only with     [Authorize]  ,
If if used     [AllowAnonymous]  I cant Get the user Id from the context

Comment: I've understand my problem more I posted Anthor Question here. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70255433/why-in-web-sockets-connections-i-cant-get-the-hubcallercontext-user  Would you please read it

Comment: Unless the token is handled by the middleware your disconnect will never be hit.